# Rails. Выборка объектов через связь has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть 3 модели:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :users, through: :tickets
end

class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :courses, through: :tickets
end
```

В **Ticket** есть поле `:status`.

Мне нужно выбрать все курсы пользователя, у которых в ticket со статусом 'paid'.

Вот рабочий код:

```
def paid
  @courses = []
  paid_tickets = current_user.tickets.where(status: 'paid')
  paid_tickets.each { |ticket| @courses << ticket.course }
  @courses
end
```

#### Но как сделать такую выборку более элегантным образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
current_user.courses.where(tickets: {status: 'paid'})
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то совсем запутался)